# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object - Python (boto3)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am attempting to enable encryption on an S3 bucket, using boto3 and the `put_bucket_encryption()` function. However, I seem to be getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

In particular, it is complaining about this line:

```
'SSEAlgorithm': 'AES256'
```

Below is my code:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-1')
s3_client.put_bucket_encryption(
  Bucket=bucket,
    ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration={
      'Rules':[
        {
           'ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault': {
              'SSEAlgorithm': 'AES256'
           }
         }
      ]   
   }
)
```

I have tried converting the whole object to string as well as just the line it is complaining about, however, to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration=json.dumps({` solve the issue ?

Comment: @DorianTurba Unfortunately not, I had already tried that. It comes out like this `{
    "Rules": [
        {
            "ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault": {
                "SSEAlgorithm": "AES256"
            }
        }
    ]
}` which is perfectly fine, but still the same error.

Comment: double quote does not solve the issue ? if not, keep it, double quote is a standard in JSON.

Comment: `'{ "Rules": [ { "ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault": { "SSEAlgorithm": "AES256" } } ] }'` solve the issue ?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the code that is throwing the error? I have copied it as is, even with those quotes and it works just fine. (the only thing that I have changed is that I have imported boto3 and replaced name of bucket)

Comment: @MatusDubrava actually you are right... I have created a lambda in the console and  tested it and it works fine.... I will review my code, but, I will leave the question open for now.